# Test graph equality in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

What's the most efficient way to test if two NetworkX graphs are identical (i.e. same set of nodes, same node attributes on each node, same set of edges and same edge attributes on each edge)? Suppose that we know the two graphs are of the same class.

Thank you for your kind answer.

Answer (score 33):

There's a function in NetworkX called ***is_isomorphic()***

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic

Here is an example from that page:

```
>>> import networkx.algorithms.isomorphism as iso
>>> G1 = nx.DiGraph()
>>> G2 = nx.DiGraph()
>>> G1.add_path([1,2,3,4],weight=1)
>>> G2.add_path([10,20,30,40],weight=2)
>>> em = iso.numerical_edge_match('weight', 1)
>>> nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G2)  # no weights considered
True
>>> nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G2, edge_match=em) # match weights
False
```

Comment: @cpburnz The function itself is very simple. You can check whether or not two graphs are identical in terms of edges and nodes. You can also check the weights.

Comment: This answer is perfect. Link to exact function ("read the docs") and an example of how to use function (for the quick debugging answer).

Comment: Note: in Networkx 2.x, add_path is in the class nx. See [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.add_path.html) `nx.add_path(G, [0, 1, 2, 3])`

Comment: Also consider to add the `node_match=...` parameter https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic.html